# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731536/finding-the-number-of-meetings-in-the-given-time) today which is a shortened version of the previous question I posted here so that users may get the point I'm trying to ask.

It's not a "check-my-work question" and neither a "home-work question".

From the given links:

> How should I ask a homework question on this website?

- See if an existing question helps you: None
- Ask about the specific concept that gives you trouble: That's what I'm asking
- Reference the source: The question is complete in itself
- Use the homework tag: Did

> I'm also conforming to everything in [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/9084#9084).

Also, I'm a new user and just closing the question despite the included details, formatting, etc. and providing no reason via comments whatsoever doesn't seem right at all. (I'm really unable to make out head or tail why the question should be closed.)

I believe that, in light of the above, the question should be opened but despite reviews it has been choosed to kept closed. Hopefully it will be opened or I'll get at least some valid and constructive comments/answers that tell me how the question that I asked is wrong, or the way that I have asked is wrong etc. so that I may improve the question in whatever way I can.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"Ask about the specific concept that gives you trouble: That's what I'm asking"* I don't see that in the current version of your question - you're just saying you don't know how to solve a specific exercise and you're asking us for the solution.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the concept as you are considering is to broad it seems and then I'm in wrong. But how I'm seeing it is the concept that when 2 bodies are moving to and fro then how many times do they meet in the given time. This might be better called the application of some concept but even that way the question shouldn't be a problem because the concept for OP essentially is Speed=Distance/Time but that really leaves me nowhere.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a physics concept that applies. This is a brain teaser problem, not one of physics. Perhaps Math SE might be better, but I would not bet on it.

Comment: From that answer: *"The best way to produce a focused, specific question is to show your work."*. There is a difference between describe and show. (If you already solved it graphically, it should be possible to come up with a mathematical equation (probably the core of the homework) and either come to an analytical result or use numerical methods if it can't be solved.)